# Shallow Neural Net for predicting numbers other then 1 or 0?

Tags: neural-network, prediction

I'm not gonna lie, I'm very new to neural networks but am also so interested in them and learning the way they work and what can be made from them. So in my endeavors for learning, I stumbled upon Siraj Ravel's youtube channel and furthermore, his Github where he posted this 1 neuron neural network that predicts the output given inputs.* I looked at it and his accompanying video and got the basic gist of how it works. After running it a few times making minor adjustments to say the inputs, I decided why not try to add numbers other than 1 and 0. I made a pattern with the output being the inputs added, however, I ran into an error where the output of its test was '1.'. I assumed this was because of the sigmoid function forcing it to be in between 1 and 0.

**Summary:** How can I change that program so I can give it an input of patterns with different numbers than 1 and 0 and it will output correctly (examples below)

*In his program inputs were like [1, 0, 1] = 1, [0, 0, 1] = 0 and [1, 0, 0] = 1 (pattern is first column of matrix is answer) and he asked the program to give output for [1, 1, 0] and it correctly outputted 1.

*My goal for it was so given "[2, 2, 2] = 6, [1, 2, 0] = 3, and [1, 1, 2] = 4 (more training included if necassary)" as input could it get 4 as output for "[2, 2, 0]?

[***Code for program***](https://github.com/llSourcell/Make_a_neural_network/blob/master/demo.py)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Without any edits, the code works, as to say it can correctly predict either the 1 or 0, I'm trying to find how I can edit it to predict other numbers, but the answer below is a very simple script for doing such, so many thanks to Andrey, @gokul_uf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the main problem is that the existing code and the desired codes solve different problems.

The existing code solves a classification problem, when you predict one of certain classes. And you want to solve a regression problem, so that neural net will predict an arbitrary number.

Sigmoid function is necessary when you predict classes, you need to remove it for regression. Or in other words you need not Logistic Regression, but Linear Regression.
Here is a great article with explanations on this: http://peterroelants.github.io/posts/neural_network_implementation_part01/

I have written an example of implementation: https://gist.github.com/Erlemar/6a5cfcca423ef3b5f6e890c6bef6d5ed

Comment: Hey, @AndreyLukyanenko , the response got me thinking (thanks for it by the way) how exactly is the first program a classification problem?

Comment: Well, strictly speaking it isn't classification indeed, it is more like finding a pattern. But using sigmoid activation makes it very similar to classification.

Comment: Do you have an idea on how I can edit the program (possibly getting rid of the sigmoid) to make it predict numbers other than 1 or 0? @AndreyLukyanenko

Comment: The key idea here is that saturating non-linearities such as the sigmoid function are good for classification, as networks will tend to learn the outcome towards two finite limits (often 0 and 1). For any other kind of regression, you can either apply another non-linearity that respects the intended output distribution, or simply have no non-linearity at the end.

Comment: @LeoC I have written a  very simple example without functions, simply one loop: https://gist.github.com/Erlemar/6a5cfcca423ef3b5f6e890c6bef6d5ed The prediction accuracy heavily depends on the randomness of weight initialization. You can improve accuracy by adding more training examples, adding more layers, changing weights initialization etc.

Comment: Thank you very much @AndreyLukyanenko , I'm in the middle of digesting your code example and thinks it's a great small program for the task, though I have a question on when you said `"prediction accuracy heavily depends on the randomness of weight initialization"`. I know all ML Neural nets benefit from randomness, but even if it wasn't 100% random, it can still self-adjust, right? I assume that's the same principle for your code right?

Comment: Of course they self adjust. There are two problems: model could stack in local mininum, then the optimal solution won't be reached; weight vector updated all values equally. First problem can be solved by tuning learning rate. Second problem can be solved by updating each value in weight vector separately - I updated the gist.